# Determine if the set $A=\{(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}) \mid n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geqslant 2 \}$ is closed in the open unit disk $B$.

Tags: general-topology

> Determine if the set $A=\{(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}) \mid n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geqslant 2 \}$ is closed in the open unit disk $B$.

A set is closed if it contains all it's limit points right? So if $x_n=(\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac1n) \to (0,1)$, and $(0,1) \notin B$ thus the set must be open?

Comment: Sets that are not closed are not automatically open, like $[0, 1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ has no limit points **inside** $B$.  Hence it contains all its limit points and it is a closed subset of $B$.

Comment: Not sure I follow. If $(0,1)$ is a limit point of $A$, but $(0,1) \notin B$, then how can $A$ be a closed subset of $B$?

Comment: @DanielLi To see if the set is closed **in** $B$ you are supposed to work completely within $B$. Just pretend that there is nothing outside the open unit disk. Now see if all limit points of $A$ belong to $A$. There are no limit points so, vacuously, $A$ contains all its limit points.

Comment: "There are no limit points", isn't $(0,1)$ a limit point of $A$?

Comment: @DanielLi $(0,1)$ is not  a point in our universal set $B$.